# Reusable Django apps + Ansible provisioning

Tags: python, django, vagrant, ansible

I'm a long-time Django developer and have just started using Ansible, after using Vagrant for the last 18 months. Historically I've created a single VM for development of all my projects, and symlinked the reusable Django apps (Python packages) I create, to the site-packages directory.

I've got a working dev box for my latest Django project, but I can't really make changes to my own reusable apps without having to copy those changes back to a Git repo. Here's my ideal scenario:

1. I checkout all the packages I need to develop as Git submodules within the site I'm working on
2. I have some way (symlinking or a better method) to tell Ansible to setup the box and install my packages from these Git submodules
3. I run `vagrant up` or `vagrant provision`
4. It reads requirements.txt and installs the remaining packages (things like South, Pillow, etc), but it skips my set of tools because it knows they're already installed

I hope that makes sense. Basically, imagine I'm developing Django. How do I tell Vagrant (via Ansible I assume) to find my local copy of Django, rather than the one from PyPi?

Currently the only way I can think of doing this is creating individual symlinks for each of those packages I'm developing, but I'm sure there's a more sensible model.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably think of it slightly differently. You create a Vagrant file which specifies Ansible as a provisioner. In that Vagrant file you also specify what playbook to use for your `vagrant provision` portion.

If your playbooks are written in an idempotent way, running them multiple times will skip steps that already match the desired state.
You should also think about what your desired end-state of a VM should look like and write playbooks to accomplish that. Unless I'm misunderstanding something, all your playbook actions should be happening inside of VM, not directly on your local machine.

Comment: Thanks @Mxx, but I might not have explained what I need properly.

Comment: Perhaps so. Try to edit your question to expand on what you are asking for. :(

Comment: I have a website, written in Django. I'm developing that site by spinning up a VM, provisioning it with Ansible and using `manage.py runserver`. I've written a Python package that adds a blog to a Django site, and I need to make some changes to it. Currently that blog module is installed from the Python Packaging Index, and any changes I make will a) not be versoned and b) disappear if I destroy the box. So what I'm asking is what's the best way to be able to develop my blog module as I work on the VM? Thanks!

Comment: btw I wasn't intending just to say "Thanks but no thanks". Think I hit return to many times and the comment got sent, so I thought it best to start a new one rather than edit the old one. Wasn't just being rude; I appreciate your help! :)

Comment: You should edit your original question with these clarifications, so that in case my answer gets removed or there's a better one, it's more organized. and don't put "thanks" in your question, it's unneeded on SE sites.